# Does granting a Facebook app permission to see my likes allow all other users of the app to see my likes as well?

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, permissions, privacy

**Does granting a Facebook app permission to see my likes allow all other users of the app to see my likes as well?**

**Or is whether another user of the same app is able to see my likes dependent upon my privacy settings for my likes?**

For example, let's say I allow only friends to see my likes. Does that mean a fellow user of the app can only see my likes if and only if he or she is also my friend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is **no.**

Take a look at the [Facebook User object reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user). Each user has a likes property that is only accessible under [extended permissions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/extended-profile-properties/) granted by the user.

A user would need to have granted this application the user_like permission to the app, for the app to be able to see that user's likes. This does not apply transitively to friends of the user.

Just because there are other users of the application they will not transitively get any permissions from you. Your public profile is just that, its public. Properties under that are always visible to all users of Facebook (apps and individual users).

Clearly the app will have access to likes from all users that have granted it the user_likes permission.

Comment: This was my understanding as well and the result of my testing. Thank you for your answer and for varying Sandeep!